# Fetch Request Not Working

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to add a custom header, `X-Query-Key`, to a HTTP request using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) but when I add this to the header of the request it appears to fail at setting the headers and the `Request Method` is set to `OPTIONS` for some reason.

When I remove the header it goes back to being `GET` as it should do.

Sample code looks like below:

```
   const options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-Query-Key': '123456' //Adding this breaks the request
    }
  };

  return request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(body);
  });
```

Comment: Sounds like CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const headers = new Headers({
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "X-Query-Key": "123456",
});

const options = {
  url: url,
  headers: headers
};

return request(options, (err, res, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

If that does not solve the issue, it may be related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode).

Comment: Thanks - This worked, guess I was missing the `Headers` - Now I get the CORS issue which is my next problem :D

Comment: I think it's because you have to invoke the constructor in order to create your own headers. Hey, at least the fetch API makes CORS much simpler to handle. The real snag with the new fetch API is that a [fetch request cannot be aborted](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27). fetch has its uses for ServiceWorkers, but in practice I've found myself using XHR2 everywhere still.

Answer (score 1):

> Custom headers on cross-origin requests must be supported by the
>   server from which the resource is requested. The server in this
>   example would need to be configured to accept the X-Custom-Header
>   header in order for the fetch to succeed. When a custom header is set,
>   the browser performs a preflight check. This means that the browser
>   first sends an OPTIONS request to the server to determine what HTTP
>   methods and headers are allowed by the server. If the server is
>   configured to accept the method and headers of the original request,
>   then it is sent. Otherwise, an error is thrown.

So you will have 2 requests if use custom headers, first one with method OPTIONS  to check if server allows custom headers and after that if the server response is 200 OK and allows your originary request the second one will be send

[Working with the Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api)